# How do I group records which have at least one field in common?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, duplicates, similarity

So, I have a pandas data frame with the following fields for a given customer:

- Customer ID
- First Name
- Last name
- Phone
- Email
- Address

Since a person might have multiple accounts with us, for examples: all the following records seem to point to the same person in real life

| customer ID | first_name | last_name | phone | email | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | Mark | johnson | 787-8778878 | mark.email@gmail.com | address_1 |
| id2 | Marc | jonson | 787-8778878 | mark.johnson@gmail.com | address_2 |
| id3 | Mark | johnsan | 875-3524666 | mark.johnson@gmail.com | address_3 |
| id4 | Mark | johnson | 432-6654221 | mark.johnson@gmail.com | address_2 |

I need to find such duplicate customer records. My plan to achieve this is to cluster all records in different groups if they share:

1. first letters of the first name AND last name
2. AT LEAST ONE attribute from phone, email, address

Once the grouping is performed, I can then check for similarity in their names within each group.

Is there a way to perform such grouping? The data frame contains 100s of millions of records so the solution should be fast as well.

Comment: Use `fuzzywuzzy` to match first and last name. Please provide a sample of your data with at least 2 accounts from a same customer

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Ideally, input example data, expected output, and code that you tested

Comment: I have added some example records. I don't have any code which can achieve such grouping. All I am able to do is apply group_by by the first letter of first name, last_name, and phone.